# Detect a pan just after a tap in Hammer.js, call it double tap and pan

Tags: javascript, gesture, hammer.js

I'm trying to detect a double-tap and pan ( tap once, then press, move and release ) with HammerJS, but I'm not sure how to do that. I read the docs, but I don't understand how I cannot detect a "simple" pan compared to a "double" tap and pan.

Actually I'm able to detect it with the following code, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

```
    var gestureManager = new Hammer.Manager( this.canvas, {
        recognizers: [
            [ Hammer.Tap ],
            [ Hammer.Pan ],
            [ Hammer.Pan, { event: 'panend' } ]
        ]
    );

    gestureManager.on( 'tap', ( ev ) => {
        this.tapTime = new Date().getTime();
    });

    gestureManager.on( 'pan', ( ev ) => {
        var panTime = new Date().getTime();

        if ( panTime - this.tapTime < 750 ) {
            this.isDragEnabled = true;

            ...
        }
    });

    gestureManager.on( 'panend', ( ev ) => {
        if ( this.isDragEnabled ) {
            ...
            this.isDragEnabled = false;
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar, trying to detect a pan after the touch has lasted some amount of time. It's based on the fact that you can enable and disable the recognizers.

```
var shortPress = new Hammer.Press({
    time: 500, // how long to press before you can start dragging
    event: 'shortPress'
});
var pan = new Hammer.Pan({ event: 'pan', enable: false });

var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element);
mc.add(shortPress);
mc.add(pan);

mc.on("shortPress", function(ev) {
    pan.set({ enable: true });
});

mc.on("pan", function(ev) {
    // do whatever you need
});

// don't forget to disable the pan recognizer when the dragging ends
mc.on("panend pancancel shortPressup", function(ev) {
    pan.set({ enable: false });
});
```

But for your double-tap and pan scenario I think it's more complicated, because you can't just switch the Press recognizer with a Tap with 2 taps, because it is only detected once you lift the finger. So it would be more something like detect a tap, enable the pan, but set a timeout to disable it if it does not start after a certain amount of time. But you already do this, and your code seems to be simpler in this case.

By the way, you probably want to also allow a press before the pan, to allow the case when you double-tap, but keep your finger still for a while, and only then move it.